# PHP: How to manually stop a method/function execution

Tags: php, angular, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a method that syncs and updates a database based on an API service. The connection to the API is made via Socket (TCP/IP). The API has a service to return all the ids of the updated items and another to get an item with the updated data. So, i created a sync method that gets the list of updated item ids, iterates the list and updates each item.
Since i have to make a socket connection inside the loop to get the item details, this process can take some time depending on the number os items to update.
For that reason i would like to allow the client to cancel/stop this process if desired.

Is this possible to accomplish with my current method? Or should i do the items iteration in the client side and change the API to update one item at each request?

The client app is in Angular and the API in PHP.

**UPDATE:** Example of the current sync method:

```
public static function syncItems()
{
    $response = -1;

    try {

        //get all updated item ids from api
        $updatedItemIds = self::getUpdatedItemIDs(); //connection to tcp/ip socket

        if (isset($updatedItemIds)) {

            $totalItems = count($updatedItemIds);
            $updatedIems = 0;

            //iterate all ids and get the item details
            foreach ($updatedItemIds as $id) {

                //get updated item data from api
                $updatedItem = self::getItemDetails($id); //connection to tcp/ip socket

                if (isset($updatedItem)) {

                    //get local version o the item
                    $item = Item::find($id);

                    //if item doesn't exist create a new one
                    if (!isset($item)) {

                        $item = new item();

                    }

                    //update item data
                    $item->id = $updatedItem->id
                    $item->name = $updatedItem->name;
                    $item->description = $updatedItem->description;                    

                    //save or update item details in DB
                    if ($item->save()) {
                        //increment updated items
                        $updateditems++;
                    } else {
                        //not saved
                    }
                } else {
                    //not set
                }
            }

            $response = $totalitems - $updateditems;
        }
        else
        {
            //no items to sync...
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {

        //ooppsss!
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Maybe think about showing some code?

Comment: Totally forgot. Done!

Comment: I don't think it would be possible unless you do a loop in javascript and update individual items one by one. You can stop javascript loop but not a server script that is already running.

Comment: @i-- that's my plan if there is no other way to accomplish this. I just wanted to keep stuff clean and do all the hard/durty work on the server side.

Comment: Technically, I suppose you could let the user send an ajax request to the server and then have that code kill the PID for that process. That could of course lead to a dangerous escalation of privileges so you'd have to construct it very carefully.

Comment: @Difster, in your opinion is it worth the risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just thought of a solution. You'd need to use sessions.
You'd want to set `$_SESSION['halt'] = false` before the `foreach()` started.

```
foreach ($updatedItemIds as $id) {
    if($_SESSION['halt'] === true)) {
    $_SESSION['halt'] = false; //set back to false immediate.
    die;
    }
 //The socket connection would never get made if the above evaluated to true.
            $updatedItem = self::getItemDetails($id); //connection to tcp/ip socket
}
```

Have a button on the user end pointing to another script which just sets `$_SESSION['halt'] == true` when clicked.

You could even set a pause in your script to slow it down and give the user more time to react, etc. if you want to.

Comment: @Ricky - If you think that will do it, don't forget to mark this as solved. Thanks!

Comment: i'm going to try it out and get back to you. I will certainly mark it :)

Comment: You should use the Laravel api `session()->put('halt', true)`

Comment: Good idea @adam - I forgot about that.

Comment: This is a creative idea, but it looks like you'd need to [start, then write and then close session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15616203/1509551) on every loop iteration & same steps for the other call that will be changing it. Alternatives could be Redis or database, although db would be overkill.

Comment: No, you wouldn't need close the session, you'd just need to set and unset the session variable. You wouldn't need a new session for each loop, just a check to see if the $_SESSION['halt'] is true or not. If it's true,, set it to false and kill the loop and it's ready to go again.

Comment: You sound pretty confident @Difster. Here is an [article for you](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2014/08/session-locking-non-blocking-read-sessions-php/) and read the first comment as well.